# Portfolio Management API

Tags: api, finance, quantitative-finance

Does anyone know of a Stock/Fund GIPS Portfolio API. An Open Source version would be preferable.
Thanks,
j.

Comment: Can you give more detail about what exactly you are looking for the api to do. The question seems a little vague.

Comment: It's best to demonstarte with an example. I need it to manage a portfolio of stocks. e.g. Mike has $100k in his portfolio. He buys £30k of worth of Google shares and $10k of Apple. A few weeks later he sells some of his stock. I need an API to calculate performance returns, current value of portfolio, net gains, etc.  The data will be supplied via a local(customised) database.

Answer (score 1):

In that case I'd suggest looking at quantlib. Used it previoisly to calculate some financial products.

Answer (score 1):

A WIP but could do some of the things you are after https://github.com/evandavey/OpenPortfolio